# How to record an panel contain animation of many controls into GIF ? (WINFORM)

Tags: c#, winforms

I have a panel like this with many controls.I want to record this panel when a event fire and end when another event fire. I lost 2 days to find solution. I hope someone can help me deal it. tks
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VGisF.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is there anything you have tried?
How about this:

Add references:

```
PresentationCore.dll
System.Xaml.dll
WindowsBase.dll
```

add variable to your form:

```
List<Bitmap> bitmapList = new List<Bitmap>();
```

Call this metod to save panel's state (gif frame)

```
private void SavePanel()
{
    Bitmap bmp = new Bitmap(panel1.Width, panel1.Height);
    panel1.DrawToBitmap(bmp, new Rectangle(0, 0, panel1.Width, panel1.Height));
    bitmapList.Add(bmp);
}
```

Call this metod to create Gif from saved frames:

```
private void SaveGif()
{
    System.Windows.Media.Imaging.GifBitmapEncoder gEnc = new System.Windows.Media.Imaging.GifBitmapEncoder();
    foreach (var bmp in bitmapList)
    {
        var hbmp = bmp.GetHbitmap();
        var src = System.Windows.Interop.Imaging.CreateBitmapSourceFromHBitmap(hbmp, IntPtr.Zero, System.Windows.Int32Rect.Empty, System.Windows.Media.Imaging.BitmapSizeOptions.FromEmptyOptions());
        gEnc.Frames.Add(System.Windows.Media.Imaging.BitmapFrame.Create(src));
    }

    using (FileStream fs = new FileStream(@"C:\panel1.gif", FileMode.Create))
    {
        gEnc.Save(fs);
    }
    bitmapList.Clear();
}
```

Comment: in old version, i used timer to make animation, and i capture screen each frame. Combine it and export to gif FILE. Now i use a library to support animation of control it make animation clear and fast. I just declare variable and use. So i cant screen each any more by timer. And i choose a solution record a panel and export to GIF file.

Comment: About your solution. I can't take a image with each animation. Can u show me a solution that we record a panel. We can use any tool to do it: a framework, a software like bandicam,.... anything to do it. Can u help me?